# How to quantify these features so they can be analysed upon using Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a very small question which has been baffling me for a while. I have a dataset with interesting features, but some of them are dimensionless quantities (I've tried using z-scores) on them but they've made things worse. These are:

```
Timestamps (Like YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMis) I am getting the last 9 chars from this.
User IDs (Like in a Hash form) How do I extract meaning from them?
IP Addresses (You know what those are). I only extract the first 3 chars.
City (Has an ID like 1,15,72) How do I extract meaning from this?
Region (Same as city) Should I extract meaning from this or just leave it?
```

The rest of the things are prices, widths and heights which understand. Any help or insight would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Timestamps can be transformed into Unix Timestamps, which are reasonable natural numbers
- User IF/Cities/Regions are nominal values, which has to be encoded somehow. The most common approach is to create as much "dummy" dimensions as the number of possible values. So if you have 100 ciries, than you create 100 dimensions and give "1" only on the one representing a particular city (and 0 on the others)
- IPs should rather be removed, or transformed into some small group of them (based on the DNS-network identification and nominal to dummy transformation as above)

Comment: Thanks, I dont get how Timestamps can add value as features, and as far as Cities and Regions are concerned, all I have are numbers, don't know what cities and regions belong to what. IPs, well, I got the first 3 chars but then it doesn't seem to be a feature to me, but maybe I am extracting the wrong information from my given data.

Comment: timestamps simply are well defined in terms of real values. They are comparable for any classifier, while your dates are not. In terms of cities - my answer does not require knowing anything about them, IDs are just fine for such encoding. Although provided list of features does not look promising (I would be suprised if anything "deeper" can be extracted from such data).

Comment: No I have meaningful data, such as width, height and other real values. Okay, you mean I should convert my dates into unix timestamps? Is that what you are saying? How does that give me an advantage when I am just extracting the HHMMDDMis part of my date.

Comment: because timestamps have **order**. HHMMDD is not sortable by the machine learning algorithms, this is pretty basic thing.